# How to fix "alert functions"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a **Join** `button` in my project where I want to output some Alert.

First function is:

```
func joinQuiz(id:String) -> QuizRespone? {
    var result:QuizRespone?
    let docRef = db.collection(QuizController.quizReferenceName).document(id)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document , document.exists {
            if DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.contains(id) ?? false  {
                result = .joined
            } else {
                DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.append(id)
                DataManager.shared.userController.joinQuiz(id: id)
                result = .notJoined
            }
        } else  {
            result = .badCode
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Actions of my button:

```
@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if titleTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
        if let result = DataManager.shared.quizController.joinQuiz(id: titleTextField.text) {
            switch result {
            case .badCode :
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "Bad code")
            case .joined:
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "You are alredy joined")
            case .notJoined:
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        } 
    }
 }
```

I expect this to output some alerts, however I'm not getting any output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase call is asynchronous you can't return something synchronously you need a completion

```
func joinQuiz(id:String,completion:@escaping((QuizRespone) -> ())) { 
    let docRef = db.collection(QuizController.quizReferenceName).document(id)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document , document.exists {
            if DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.contains(id) ?? false  {
                completion(.joined)
            } else {
                DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.append(id)
                DataManager.shared.userController.joinQuiz(id: id)
                completion(.notJoined)
            }
        } else  {
            completion(.badCode)
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if titleTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
       DataManager.shared.quizController.joinQuiz(id: titleTextField.text) { result  in 
            switch result {
            case .badCode :
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "Bad code")
            case .joined:
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "You are alredy joined")
            case .notJoined:
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the document works asynchronously, you can't return something from that function, add a completion handler and there is no reason to declare `QuizRespon(s)e` as optional

```
func joinQuiz(id:String, completion: @escaping (QuizRespone)->Void)  {
    let docRef = db.collection(QuizController.quizReferenceName).document(id)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document , document.exists {
            if DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.contains(id) ?? false  {
                completion(.joined)
            } else {
                DataManager.shared.userController.user.following?.append(id)
                DataManager.shared.userController.joinQuiz(id: id)
                completion(.notJoined)
            }
        } else  {
            completion(.badCode)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func createAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if titleTextField.text.isEmpty == false {
        if let result = DataManager.shared.quizController.joinQuiz(id: titleTextField.text) { response in
            switch response {
            case .badCode :
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "Bad code")
            case .joined:
                self.showErrorAlert(message: "You are alredy joined")
            case .notJoined:
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }
        } 
    }
 }
```